# remove first label in inline enumitem

Tags: lists, enumitem, inline

I'm using an inline enumitem with bullets, but I would like there to be no bullet before the first item. After reading the manual, I tried the following, but it still leaves an unwanted space before the first item. I tried to eliminate that by setting the labelsep to 0, but that had no effect. Is there any good way to do this?

Minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}

This is a short paragraph

\begin{enumerate*}[label={}, itemjoin={~\textbullet}]
\item First item\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate*}

This is another short paragraph

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to set `afterlabel={}`, so nothing is added after the empty label:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\begin{document}

This is a short paragraph

\begin{enumerate*}[
  label={},
  itemjoin={~\textbullet\ },
  afterlabel={},
]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate*}

This is another short paragraph

\end{document}
```

[image]